# perl datetime truncate fails when falling into a DST time shift

Tags: perl, datetime, timezone, dst

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;

my $dt = DateTime->new( {
               year => 2014, month => 10,  day => 19, 
               hour => 2,  minute=> 2,  second=> 0
});
$dt->set_time_zone(DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => 'America/Sao_Paulo' ));
$dt->truncate(to => 'day');
```

is failing with a message `Invalid local time for date in time zone: America/Sao_Paulo`.

Because `2014-10-19 00:00:00` is not a valid time in `America/Sao_Paulo` timezone. The end result should be `2014-10-19 01:00:00`.

#### My theory in pseudocode

```
Try to truncate directly to the datetime object inside an eval

IF fails
   IF the truncation level is "day"
      -1 day 
      truncate
      + seconds of a day
   IF the truncation level is "month"
      -1 month 
      truncate
      seconds of a month. <--- Now here I need to take care of seconds of every month and even leapyear
 ELSE im happy
```

Any help to improve my theory or provide a much simpler approach?

Comment: Presumably the call to `new` should come *before* the call to `set_time_zone`?

Comment: ah right... thats just a result of my writing the example code directly in SO instead of copy paste. Will change it.

Comment: Are you saying that Sao Paulo enters daylight saving time at midnight on 18 October?

Comment: yes 2014-10-18 23:59:59 is followed by 2014-10-19 01:00:00. You can refer to http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/brasilia

Comment: Though I mentioned about month level truncation here, I believe a month level truncate operation will never fail because I dont see any country switching there times at midnight on the first day of a  month.

Comment: @ikegami: I just want my own definition `truncate` method that always return correct result rather than throwing exception like DateTime::truncate method.

Comment: That would be wrong for `truncate`, but a method that returns the start of the day would indeed be nice. As the answer of the other question says "You'd think this is something that needs to be done commonly! I suspect there's a lot of buggy code out there..."

Answer (score 0):

Since the error occurs only when the hour is being set to zero, the correction must always be to set the hour to one instead. Zones where the hour changes other than at midnight won't have the problem.

That means you can write a trivial exception handler like this.

I'm tempted to say that no zone starts daylight saving on the first day of a month, so the problem shouldn't occur when truncating to the month. But I can't guarantee that, so I've coded a block for that as well.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;
use Try::Tiny;

my $dt = DateTime->new( {
    year => 2014, month => 10,  day => 19, 
    hour => 2,  minute=> 2,  second=> 0
});

my $sao_paolo = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => 'America/Sao_Paulo' );

$dt->set_time_zone($sao_paolo);

try {
  $dt->truncate(to => 'day');
}
catch {
  die $_ unless /Invalid local time for date/;
  $dt->truncate(to => 'hour');
  $dt->set({hour => 1});
};

say $dt;

try {
  $dt->truncate(to => 'month');
}
catch {
  die $_ unless /Invalid local time for date/;
  $dt->truncate(to => 'hour');
  $dt->set({day => 1, hour => 1});
};

say $dt;
```

**output**

```
2014-10-19T01:00:00
2014-10-01T00:00:00
```

Comment: @ikegami: It shifts the problem *only* when DST starts at midnight. It can't start at midnight *and* at 01:00

Comment: so try..catch approach is the go then?

Comment: Actually, shifts are two hours are possible, but less likely, which is why I had already removed my comment.